# Laravel Get Count Based on Subordinate Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm doing my best to figure out how to make this work, but I am uncertain of the right way to go about this. I want to track a pharmacy's metrics, specifically how many patients a pharmacy fills or refills during a month. Ideally, this could happen by counting the amount of `patients` or `scripts` that were filled by the `fill_date` in the `prescription` model.

For example, `patient` John Smith could be written a `script` on 1/1/18, but receive `prescriptions` on 1/1/18, 2/1/18, and 3/1/18. I would want these refills to be tracked in my metrics - but done by `patient` or `script`. So that we can know how many patients (original fills or refills) went through each month.

Here is a breakdown of my models and relationships:

**Patients/Scripts**

`patients` have many `scripts`, where `scripts` can only have 1 `patient`. A patient is what you expect: a patient of a doctor. They go in to a doctor's office usually once and has a script written for them. Scripts are the documents that doctors write for patients. They will write this for the patient and send it to the pharmacy. Each script has a `prescribe_date` to show when the patient had a script written for them.

**Scripts/Prescriptions**

`scripts` have many `prescriptions`, where `prescriptions` can only have 1 `script`. When the pharmacy receives a script, they will see what the patient's insurance can cover, then fill a prescription. Prescriptions are what the patient is approved for and received, and will likely receive multiple months in a row if they have refills for their prescriptions. Each prescription has a `fill_date` to show when they received their fill/refill.

**Pharmacies**

`pharmacies` have many `scripts`, where `scripts` can only have 1 `pharmacy`. The pharmacy is an identifier tagged to the script written so that we can track a pharmacy's metrics.

Here is my code:

**Pharmacy Model (linking prescriptions through scripts relationship)**

```
// Pharmacies have many Scripts relationship
public function prescriptions() {
    $this->load(['scripts.prescriptions' => function($query) use (&$relation) {
        $relation = $query;
    }]);

    return $relation;
}
```

**Variable**

```
$patients_current_month = $pharmacy
    ->prescriptions()
    ->whereBetween('fill_date', [$first_day_current_month, $last_day_current_month])
    ->count();
```

Using this will give me the total count of `prescriptions` by pharmacy for the month, but I have tried multiple scenarios and can't find a way to make it display the count of the number of patients that had a `fill_date` (from their prescriptions) that month.

Answer (score 0):

Script and Pre**script**ion mean the same thing. You don't need to have two tables for that. However you will need a "drug" table and "coverage" pivot table if you are trying to find out what drugs a patients drug plan will allow for. You will also need an "inventory" pivot table.

I'm not going to tell you all of the relations, as I feel you can figure those out yourself and it would make the answer way too long. Almost all of my code will be pseudocode.

Here's what I came up with:

**Patient**

`id|name`

**Prescription**

`id|patient_id|doctor_id|is_filled|pharmacy_id|drug_id|reason|timestamps|`

**Drug**

`id|name|timestamps`

**Pharmacy**

`id|name`

**Inventory**

`drug_id|pharmacy_id`

**Coverage**

`patient_id|drug_id`

Note, you can use tables as a pivot table by adding extra stuff to be out put withPivot. This may come handy for you Prescriptions table.

```
//Patient.php
public function drugs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Pharmacy::class, 'prescription')->withPivot('pharmacy_id');
}

//Gets how many prescriptions a patient has at pharmacy between dates
Patient::withCount(['prescription.drugs '=> function($query) use ($first_day_current_month, $last_day_current_month, $pharmacy_id){
    $query->where('pharmacy_id', $pharmacy_id);
    $query->whereBetween('created_at',[$first_day_current_month, $last_day_current_month]) //You can use whereBetween for dates
}])->get();

//Counts prescriptions filled by Pharmacy for a drug

Pharmacy::withCount(['drug' => function($query) use ($drug_id){
    $query->where('drug_id', $drug_id);
    //You can also count haw many drugs were sold at a pharmacy here 
    //and between what dates.
}])->get();
```

The boolean field is_filled on prescriptions gives you the ability to see what a patient is getting filled or not. If you want you can make that a column where not filled = 0, filled = 1, refill = 3.

I'm using a lot of [constraint eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) to accomplish things you want.